# ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 247 bytes

Tags: laravel-4

I was programming in laravel 4 when suddenly my system turned off.
I restarted machine and xampp server.

I'm getting `ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 247 bytes`

I tried doing a `php artisan cache:clear` at the prompt, but that didn't fix it.

Plz anyone give answer......

Answer (score 2):

Open command Prompt 
Go to the project directory
and type the command **php artisan cache:clear** and then **php artisan key:generate**
These commands will clear all the cached data of the project and will regenerate the key for the same.

Answer (score 0):

just install a new laravel and copy all your files from the last installation and paste them in the new directory.